What options may be turned on to debug the occasional crash whose stacktrace indicates there is an unexpected recursion?
The program crashes at a probability of 2/810 when STR (i.e. suspend to resume in QNX which contributes the low cost for the embeded devices) is triggered.
Here is the stacktrace:
#0  0x00000055f55b5afc in ?? ()
#1  0x0000004b6a42a9b8 in qnx_slog2::log_output (level=2, str=..., this=<optimized out>) at /mnt/nfs/qnx710/target/qnx7/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1520
#2  qnx_slog2::log_output (str=..., level=2, this=<optimized out>) at /home/jhone/qnx_slog2.hpp:103
#3  OMSResultSender::<lambda()>::operator()(void) const (__closure=<optimized out>) at /home/jhone/oms_result_sender.cpp:135
#4  0x0000004b6a42a9b8 in qnx_slog2::log_output (level=2, str=..., this=<optimized out>) at /mnt/nfs/qnx710/target/qnx7/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1520
#5  qnx_slog2::log_output (str=..., level=2, this=<optimized out>) at /home/jhone/qnx_slog2.hpp:103
#6  OMSResultSender::<lambda()>::operator()(void) const (__closure=<optimized out>) at /home/jhone/oms_result_sender.cpp:135
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

There is no recursion in the source project indeed. The stacktrace is very odd.
Here are the options that the program is compiled with:
-g -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-deprecated-declarations -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++14

For more detail, say related code snippet, see this question.
I will try to use the -g -O0 -DDEBUG to recompile the program to find out where goes wrong.
I searched and found that these options may help
-fstack-protector-all
-fsanitize=address
-fsanitize=undefined

But it's a pity -fsanitize=address and -fsanitize=undefined are not supported by the compiler, here is what the compiler complains.
# aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-g++ -fsanitize=address demo.cpp  
aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0-ld: cannot find -lasan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Are there any options that I should turn on to better debug the said crash?
Updated:
It is unfortunate that the program frequently crashes when the options -fstack-protector-all -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined are enabled, which is unexpected.

Logging, logging and more logging. That's basically all you can do if you can't run remote debugging (with e.g. gdbserver).

@Someprogrammerdude I see. But the program exactly crashes in logging. You see qnx_slog2::log_output is the method to write log messages by slog2. Remote debugging is not available for  embeded QNX.

The message "previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)" is an indication of your program going out of bounds of stack-allocated data (for example local variables, including arrays), not about recursion which should show up as the same function being called over and over again.

And the address 0x0000000000000000 is an indication of the program using a null-pointer.

@Someprogrammerdude 1. going out of bounds of stack-allocated data. Is there any good method/tool to locate where goes wrong?  2. 0x0000000000000000 is an indication of the program using a null-pointer Thank you for pointing out that. I am still confused that the should crash at once when the program try to access a nullptr, . But the backstrace indicates that there are still several functions have been called after the nullptr has been accessed. How do you think about it?

@John if the program using a nullptr, it should crash once. -- No.

Using a null-pointer leads to undefined behavior. Which might cause a crash, or not. My guess is that you have pointers to objects of some class, and one of those pointers are a null-pointer. Then when you call a member function of that object, it might lead to get a situation like that. Unless you need pointers for polymorphism, my recommendation is that you don't use pointers at all.
